# Node.js and mysql undefined function

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, function, return

I am writing this function with node.js, inside the function it gives me the right output, but when I try to call it from the outside it gives me undefined.
Do you have some idea why it doesn't work?

```
 var inquinamento=function(){
 connection.query('select livelloInquinamento from livInquinamento;',function(err,rows,fields){
 console.log(rows);
 return rows.livelloInquinamento;
 });
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
const data = await connection.query('select livelloInquinamento from livInquinamento');
```

and data will have row and fields and wrap this line in an async function